# Intel 7265 does not work after sleep mode

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi

This is with a HP Pavillion laptop, using Ubuntu with dual boot with Windows.

In particular, the adapter only works when I do a hard reboot - i.e. I power off the computer, then hold the power button for about 30 secs until a new boot starts and almost immediately stops. After that I have to press the power button again so that it boots and the wifi adapter is found/works. If my laptop enters sleep mode a similar problem occurs where the wifi adapter is occasionally found (not always, sometimes it disappears as in the above case), but then it does not find any networks.

I have disabled fast startup in Windows. There is an airplane mode button under f12, but no option to disable it in bios - there are no other hardware wifi switches/buttons that I can see. I have checked that I am running the latest `iwlwifi` firmware (-29.ucode) for my adapter (7265D) based on https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi.

I am attaching the full dmesg output of when the wifi is failing - one particular suspicious line (ignoring the kernel module faults at the bottom of the file for the moment) is `[Sun Jan  7 18:03:21 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Unable to change power state from D3hot to D0, device inaccessible`.

I tried googling around for the message (and the messages of the iwlwifi kernel module faults) but with not much luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

1. `dmesg | grep wifi` when failing - only partial output because of character limit and the number of stacktraces

```
[Sun Jan  7 15:56:17 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[Sun Jan  7 15:56:17 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.4063824552.0 7265D-29.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[Sun Jan  7 15:56:17 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
[Sun Jan  7 15:56:17 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[Sun Jan  7 15:56:17 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[Sun Jan  7 15:56:17 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: base HW address: c8:21:58:3c:8d:db, OTP minor version: 0x0
[Sun Jan  7 15:56:18 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
[Sun Jan  7 15:56:20 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[Sun Jan  7 15:56:20 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[Sun Jan  7 15:56:20 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:21 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Unable to change power state from D3hot to D0, device inaccessible
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024] WARNING: CPU: 7 PID: 900 at drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/trans.c:2170 __iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x18e/0x1a0 [iwlwifi]
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024] Modules linked in: rfcomm nf_tables libcrc32c nfnetlink ccm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep snd_ctl_led snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio binfmt_misc snd_soc_avs snd_soc_hda_codec snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_core snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine intel_tcc_cooling x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_hda_intel coretemp iwlmvm kvm_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi mei_hdcp mei_pxp intel_rapl_msr nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec mac80211 uvcvideo snd_hda_core snd_hwdep nouveau kvm i915 snd_pcm libarc4 irqbypass videobuf2_vmalloc snd_seq_midi crct10dif_pclmul mxm_wmi polyval_clmulni polyval_generic drm_ttm_helper ghash_clmulni_intel btusb drm_buddy sha512_ssse3 snd_seq_midi_event videobuf2_memops snd_rawmidi ttm aesni_intel videobuf2_v4l2 hp_wmi btrtl snd_seq crypto_simd iwlwifi btbcm cryptd videodev btintel processor_thermal_device_pci_legacy drm_display_helper sparse_keymap rapl btmtk processor_thermal_device
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024] RIP: 0010:__iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x18e/0x1a0 [iwlwifi]
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024]  ? __iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x18e/0x1a0 [iwlwifi]
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024]  ? __iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x18e/0x1a0 [iwlwifi]
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024]  ? __iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x18e/0x1a0 [iwlwifi]
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024]  iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x1b/0x50 [iwlwifi]
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024]  iwl_write_prph_delay+0x28/0x80 [iwlwifi]
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024]  iwl_pcie_apm_init+0x148/0x1e0 [iwlwifi]
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024]  iwl_trans_pcie_start_hw+0xa4/0x310 [iwlwifi]
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: iwlwifi device config registers:
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000000: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000020: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000040: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000060: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000080: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 000000a0: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 000000c0: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 000000e0: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000100: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000120: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000140: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: iwlwifi device memory mapped registers:
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000000: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000020: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: iwlwifi parent port (0000:00:1c.5) config registers:
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.5: 00000000: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.5: 00000020: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.5: 00000040: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.5: 00000060: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.5: 00000080: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.5: 000000a0: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.5: 000000c0: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.5: 000000e0: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.5: 00000100: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.5: 00000120: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.5: 00000140: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.5: 00000160: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.5: 00000180: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.5: 000001a0: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.5: 000001c0: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.5: 000001e0: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:24 2024] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.5: 00000200: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to start INIT ucode: -5
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -5
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Collecting data: trigger 16 fired.
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 900 at drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwl-trans.h:1418 iwl_fwrt_dump_lmac_error_log+0x501/0x590 [iwlwifi]
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] Modules linked in: rfcomm nf_tables libcrc32c nfnetlink ccm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep snd_ctl_led snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio binfmt_misc snd_soc_avs snd_soc_hda_codec snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_core snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine intel_tcc_cooling x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_hda_intel coretemp iwlmvm kvm_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi mei_hdcp mei_pxp intel_rapl_msr nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec mac80211 uvcvideo snd_hda_core snd_hwdep nouveau kvm i915 snd_pcm libarc4 irqbypass videobuf2_vmalloc snd_seq_midi crct10dif_pclmul mxm_wmi polyval_clmulni polyval_generic drm_ttm_helper ghash_clmulni_intel btusb drm_buddy sha512_ssse3 snd_seq_midi_event videobuf2_memops snd_rawmidi ttm aesni_intel videobuf2_v4l2 hp_wmi btrtl snd_seq crypto_simd iwlwifi btbcm cryptd videodev btintel processor_thermal_device_pci_legacy drm_display_helper sparse_keymap rapl btmtk processor_thermal_device
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] RIP: 0010:iwl_fwrt_dump_lmac_error_log+0x501/0x590 [iwlwifi]
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024]  ? iwl_fwrt_dump_lmac_error_log+0x501/0x590 [iwlwifi]
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024]  ? iwl_fwrt_dump_lmac_error_log+0x501/0x590 [iwlwifi]
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024]  ? iwl_fwrt_dump_lmac_error_log+0x501/0x590 [iwlwifi]
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024]  ? iwl_fwrt_dump_lmac_error_log+0xec/0x590 [iwlwifi]
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024]  iwl_fwrt_dump_error_logs+0x29/0x220 [iwlwifi]
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024]  iwl_trans_sync_nmi_with_addr+0xa6/0x140 [iwlwifi]
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024]  iwl_trans_pcie_sync_nmi+0x68/0x80 [iwlwifi]
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024]  iwl_fw_dbg_error_collect+0x60/0xe0 [iwlwifi]
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: HW error, resetting before reading
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 29.4063824552.0 7265D-29.ucode
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status0
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | branchlink2
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | interruptlink1
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | interruptlink2
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | data1
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | data2
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf low
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp2
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode revision type
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode version major
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode version minor
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | hw version
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | board version
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | hcmd
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr0
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr2
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr3
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | flow_handler
[Sun Jan  7 18:03:27 2024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 0
```

Edit: `uname -a` output

```
Linux toaster 6.2.0-39-generic #40~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Nov 16 10:53:04 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Edit 2:

```
cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS"
```

Edit 3: `uname -a` output after update

```
Linux smakson-toaster 6.5.0-14-generic #14~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Nov 20 18:15:30 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled

Comment: Uf apologies, that was a dumb oversight on my part - I'll edit the question in a moment with the relevant info. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Added `lsb-release` as well, I thought the 22.04.01 in the `uname` output showed the version. It seems that my kernel was since updated by the update manager, as `uname` is now showing `6.5` which you suggested is the correct version. The issue still persists however. Please let me know if you need any other info about the Ubuntu release.

Comment: FYI:  The details provided in `uname`, beyond obvious kernel details, are mostly just packaging information; the .1 (after 22.04) tells you it's not the initial kernel released with 22.04, and remains that regardless of whether or not you're using (22.04.1, .2, ... .5) as its packaging info only (you'll note both 6.2 kernel from 22.04.3 & 6.5 from 22.04.4 (*which has started rolling out; your system will only report as 22.04.4 when you've got **all** upgrades thus still .3; `base-files` being last update to roll out*) include the .1).